# OpenCV crashes when cloning a mat (was: Is this a bug in OpenCV 3?)

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this code in opencv 3 which crashes:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   cv::Mat image1(100, 100, CV_8UC1);
   cv::Mat image2 = image1.clone();
}
```

This code crashes on clone line with this error:

```
 Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF62E41992B in test_aoolication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000000000000D.
```

Is it a bug in OpenCV 3 or I am doing something strange?

Comment: works fine here. any chance you're mixing release/debug libs ?

Comment: @berak Are you using Opencv 3.0.0? The beta version? I am sure that it works on OpenCv 2.x, but I am not able to run it in openCV 3.0.0

Comment: using locally built src, unfortunately. (also, last week's github, so probably even a bit fresher than yours)

Comment: @berak Which version of opencv do you use?

Comment: 3.0.0-alpha-1760-g3733763(on win), 3.0.0-beta-539-g08dd1e0
(on linux) , all no problem

Comment: Also make sure you are using the correct libs/dlls for you compiler. vc12 = Visual Studio 2013. vc11 = Visual Studio 2012. vc10 = Visual Studio 2010. vc9 = Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on some comments which reported they have no problem, I did more search and I found that the problem was I did not include opencv.hpp to my *.cpp file.

Interestingly, I did not get any compile time error and I was able to compile and run application.

So if you have strange behavior in openCV,  make sure that you included  to your code!

Comment: The problem seems associated with clone function. I am getting the error too and it seems that deep down in clone, while copying the Mat is released for some reason